# javascript to access a certain div class and set font Family for all of them

Tags: javascript, html, font-family

I have multiple classes of `<div class="collapsible-header">` in my markup file, i was wondering if its possible to use javascript to get all elements with that tag and set the font-family to `Roboto`
Here is a sample section of the file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:width="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<!--libraries and references-->
</head>
<body>
 <div class="collapsible-header" >
     <span class="material-icons" style="font-size: 50px">
developer_mode
      </span>
     <span style="text-align: right">Cross Platform</span>
</div>
      

<div class="collapsible-body"><span>With Java's Virtual Machine, any program written in Java can be ported to Windows, Solaris, Linux, macOS and
          ran with success.</span></div>

<script>
<!--Code to get all tags with that class and set font to Roboto-->
</script>
```

Comment: It certainly is possible. What is the issue you're struggling with?

Comment: @CodeTiger, which tag or class you want to target and apply "Font-Family" Roboto?

Comment: @Riyaz Khan, all classes with ```collapsible-header```

Comment: @Emiel Zuuriber, those tags are too many for me to keep styling, i just want to iterate through all of them with js if its possible

Comment: @CodeTiger Well, like I said, it is possible. But the question begs, in what part of making that work  lies the issue?

Comment: I dont know how to do it

Comment: i tried this with jquery but am stuck ` document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible-header');
    elems.fo
   });`

Comment: Why don't you just use CSS? Looping through elements and changing their font seems like not a good solution.

Comment: @Roland Ruul, i want to explore the power of javascript

Answer (score 2):

You can select elements multiple elements from the page with [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```js
const headers = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible-header');
```

This will return an iterable object which you can loop over. For each found element set the `style.fontFamily` property to the string `'Roboto'`. This will set the inline style of that element.

```js
for (const header of headers) {
  header.style.fontFamily = 'Roboto';
}
```

However, inline styles are hard to work with as they tend to require `!important` statements to overwrite. The preferred method would be to write a class with the font-family specified..

```css
.font-roboto {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

..and add that class to each element found by the query.

```js
for (const header of headers) {
  header.classList.add('font-roboto');
}
```

But, isn't it just possible to add CSS like so? That would do the same but without having to use JavaScript.

```css
.collapsible-header {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;
}
```

Note: the `!important` statement is not mandatory, but I guess you're having problems with overwriting styles because of specificity.

Comment: Yes exactly, document contains very may tags with that class so i just needed a shortcut method to set the font

Comment: What do you mean with *shortcut method* and what should that look like?

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
var all = document.getElementsByClassName('collapsible-header');
for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
  all[i].style.fontFamily = 'Roboto';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, i was really hoping for something like this, lemme test it

Comment: It worked, Huh thanks, i got like a thousand paragraphs with that tag, you nailed it

Comment: Perfect, if worked, please mark as a solution ;)

Comment: Done that, system says will accept in one minute

Answer (score 1):

You can use [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all class elements and then **loop over it** to apply the FontFamily style "Roboto", like below:

```js
window.onload = (event) => {
  var allCollapseHeaders = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible-header');
  
  allCollapseHeaders.forEach(header => {
    header.style.fontFamily = "Roboto"
  })

};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:width="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<!--libraries and references-->
</head>
<body>
 <div class="collapsible-header" >
     <span class="material-icons" style="font-size: 50px">
developer_mode
      </span>
     <span style="text-align: right">Cross Platform</span>
</div>
      

<div class="collapsible-body"><span>With Java's Virtual Machine, any program written in Java can be ported to Windows, Solaris, Linux, macOS and
          ran with success.</span></div>
```